# SpringBootTest: No servlet with name springServlet defined in web.xml

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to write integration tests for my spring boot 3 application. During test execution the first thing is logging in with a test user and retrieve a JSESSIONID cookie (I use form login). after login it starts running though my test case and during each case, when it wants to fire an HTTP request it gets the following exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> GET request for
> "http://localhost:60401/rest/user/USR-df97d8a9-6c38-4f0a-9e85-5a4170e38d7b":
> Server redirected too many times (20)
>
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
> at
> etc ...

On Server side I get the following exception (ca. 20 times):

> 10:46:28.227 [http-nio-auto-1-exec-8] ERROR
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [No
> servlet with name 'springServlet' defined in web.xml] with root cause
> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: No servlet with name 'springServlet'
> defined in web.xml    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:129)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
>
> etc ...

My Application is configured as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableVaadin
@Push
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

The IT configuration:

```
@ActiveProfiles("no-vaadin") 
public class XXXIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
    ... 
}
```

--

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class AbstractIntegrationTest {


    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port;
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    ...
}
```

no-vaadin profile:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinScopesConfig,com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringSecurityAutoConfiguration,com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringBootAutoConfiguration
```

Any idea what the problem could be? I assume it might be related to authentication, but when I run it locally in a normal way I have no problems.

*** EDIT ***

I did a little bit of more digging:
In my application, as you can see, I try to prevent vaadin to boot up (using profile no-vaadin and excluding autoconfig of com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinScopesConfig,com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringSecurityAutoConfiguration,com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringBootAutoConfiguration)

However, in the DispatcherServlet when Spring wants to get the HandlerExecutionChain, there is still a VaadinServletConfiguration.RootExcludeHandler, which is responsible for the 'springServlet' (see screenshot)

[image]

When I want to add that VaadinServletConfiguration to the list of exclusions in my application-no-vaadin.yml (or try to exclude it via annotation) I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes
> could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
>
> - com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletConfiguration

how can I exclude that configuration or prevent the RootExcludeHandler to be included?